# Prove $\Bbb{Z}_{100} \times \Bbb{Z}_{10}$ is not isomorphic to $\Bbb{Z}_{1000}$

Tags: group-theory

How does one prove $\Bbb{Z}_{100} \times \Bbb{Z}_{10}$ is not isomorphic to $\Bbb{Z}_{1000}$

Do you have to show one is cyclic and the one isn't? (why does this work?)

Comment: That's one way. Another revolves around the orders of elements.

Comment: For example, $Z_{1000}$ has exactly one element of order $2$, while the other has three elements of order $2$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, that's basically what I think you're supposed to do (although there are definitely other approaches that work just as well). The most straight-forward way to do that would be to show that any element of $\Bbb Z_{100}\times\Bbb Z_{10}$ has order which divides $100$, and therefore there is no element with order $1000$.

Comment: what do you mean by has order divisible by $100$? not exceed $100$, maybe?

Comment: @Azlif I think he means order a factor of $100$. Just a typo.

Comment: @Azlif Yes, a typo. I fixed it.